# Are we better in computing integrals than mathematicians of 19th century?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, integration, motives, mixed-hodge-structure

When I started to learn mathematics, I was fascinating by legendary «Демидович»: [problems in mathematical analysis](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~vybiral/MAII-2016/Demidovich-Problems-in-Mathematical-Analysis.pdf). Fifteen years later, when I open chapters about integrals, I see a long list of periods of mixed motives and generalizations of those. In particular, for almost each integral I can try to construct an appropriate algebraic variety, look at the weights on cohomology and so on. Is all this information helpful in understanding these integrals? I think yes. Here are three examples.

***Abelian integrals***

We fix a polynomial relation $P(x,y)=0$ and consider integrals
$$
\int_a^b R(x,y)dx,
$$
where $R$ is a rational function. Here the theory of Abelian functions suggests that the genus of the normalization of the curve $P(x,y)=0$ is the key invariant. For instance, if $g=0$ it leads to Ostrogradsky method and Euler substitutions, described in Demidovich’s book.

***Mixed Tate Motives unramified over $\mathbb{Z}$***
When I see an integral like
$$
\int_{0\leq x\leq y\leq 1} \frac{dx}{1-x} \frac{dy}{y}
$$
I can interpret it as a period of a cohomology group 
$$
H^2(\overline{M_{0, 5}}-A, B-A \cap B)) \quad.
$$ 
This group carries mixed Hodge structure of mixed Tate type, so we are dealing with mixed Tate motive. One can check that it is unramified 
over $\mathbb{Z}$. A theorem of Francis Brown implies that the integral above is a rational linear combination of multiple zeta values.

***More general mixed Tate motives***

This is conjectural. Consider an integral, defining a period of mixed Tate type. In view of Goncharov conjectures this integral should be a rational linear combination of multiple polylogarithms. This implies in particular that volumes of hyperbolic polytopes in all dimensions could be expressed via multiple polylogarithms.

**Question:** I would like to know about other general approaches to computing integrals and see more explicit examples of those. Here by “computing” I mean restricting significantly the set of functions, containing the answer, like in the examples above.

Comment: what does it mean to understand an integral? An integral may converge or diverge, it if it converges its value, generally speaking, is a random real number. Not much could be said about random real numbers. Is this what you are looking for? Probably not, but then it would be helpful if you specify exactly what you want.

Comment: If one restricts to some class of integrals, there is a hope to express all integral in the class via a relatively small subset of those viewed as "special functions". In these case the numbers you obtain are far from being random. You can look at the paper by Kontsevich and Zagier (https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kontzagi.pdf) for a general setup of motivic periods.

Comment: OK, I see. I think in the motivic science you restrict to rational functions or something like that. Maybe you could phrase your question in a different way, something like "for which classes of functions there is a more conceptual point of view on integrals?". Note that at the moment this comment is posted, the question says "general approaches to understanding integrals", which I personally find misleading.

Comment: Actually, there is a more general notion of exponential periods. Hypergeometric functions, Bessel functions and so on also could be analyzed using cohomology with coefficients in a local system. So almost any integral I have ever seen in a textbook fits in some natural class like that.

Comment: @DaniilRudenko : The title of the question does not seem to match the question in the main body. The title mentions *computing* integrals while the body focuses on *understanding* the integrals. Are you really interested in whether these geometric insights lead to *computational* improvements? Or are you just interested in which classical integrals have a geometric interpretation?

Comment: I am certainly interested in computing them. By computing I mean restricting the class of answers one will get, like “a linear combination of polylogarithms, whose arguments are algebraic functions”. I will edit the formulation, since it causes confusion.

Comment: But, as @kartop_man says, an integral is a number (except that your first example of integrals, which mentions $P(x, y)$ but integrates $R(x, y)$ with no indication of the connection between them, depends on an extra parameter).  Every integral (without parameters) can be computed merely in terms of *constant* functions—so I think you need to state a more precise question to keep this from being too broad.  That would be a shame, because I think it is an interesting question!

Comment: (Oh, I guess the extra parameter $y$ that I mentioned is implicit-ed out by the polynomial relation $P(x, y) = 0$, and that that explains the relationship between $P(x, y)$ and $R(x, y)$—although I'm still not sure how you deal with branch points.)

Comment: @LSpice You are right, the question is not precise, but I don’t know how to formulate it more clearly, without restricting the class of examples too much. In Example 2 an integral can not depend on parameters, so one would expect to restrict the set of numbers one can get. In example 3 one can consider arbitrary variation of mixed Tate motives, so parameters may appear.

Comment: @LSpice What kind of branch points do you mean?

Comment: Points where the Jacobian of $P$ is singular.

Comment: I think that you can just look at the normalization of the curve $P=0$  and pull the integral back there.

Comment: For functions with elementary integrals, there is Risch algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm