# Different occurences of the word 'period' in algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I have come across the word 'period' in several contexts and I wonder if these notions are related.

(1) The period map and domain: Let $ \pi : X \rightarrow B $ be a proper holomorphic submersion of complex manifolds. If a fiber $ X_0 $ of $ \pi $ is (compact) Kahler, then the cohomology groups $ H^k(X_0, \mathbb{Z}) $ (modulo torsion) are Hodge structures of weight $ k $. Now if we consider a small enough neighborhood $ U $ of $ 0 \in B $, then all fibers of U are Kahler, the Hodge numbers $ h^{p,q} $ are constant, and there is a fixed isomorphism (#) $ H^k(X_b, \mathbb{C}) \cong H^k(X_0, \mathbb{C}) $ from Ehresmann's theorem. So the numbers $ a_p = \text{dim} F^pH^k(X_b, \mathbb{C}) $ are also constant. The period map then sends $ b \in U $ to the (image under (#) of the) flag $ \{F^pH^k(X_b, \mathbb{C})\}_p $ in the flag variety $ G(a_k , \ldots , a_1, H^k(X_0, \mathbb{C})) $. The period domain is the subset of the flag variety whose flags satisfy $ F^pH^k(X_0, \mathbb{C}) \oplus \overline{F^{k+1-p}H^k(X_0, \mathbb{C})} = H^k(X_0, \mathbb{C}) $.

(2) Period: A real number is a period if it is an integral $ \int_{p \ge 0} q(x_1, \ldots, x_n) dx $ where $ p $ is a polynomial with rational coefficients and $ q $ is a rational function with rational coefficients. We can allow $p,q $ to be algebraic functions, this is equivalent. So abelian integrals $ \int_0^r \frac{dx}{\sqrt
{4x^3 - ax - b}} $ are periods ($ r,a,b \in \mathbb{Q} $).

(3) Period of a cohomology group: I came across this notion after reading Daniil Rudenko's [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332387/are-we-better-in-computing-integrals-than-mathematicians-of-19th-century) on this website. This one I do not understand at all.

So my question is: How are these notions related? Surely (2) and (3) are related as you're supposedly computing an integral in (3) as well. And I suspect (1) and (3) are related as well as you're dealing with some cohomology group.

I apologize if the question is a bit too general but I'd like to understand this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second and the third are pretty much equivalent.
Indeed, "the period" in XIX century sense is essentially
the same as the discrepancy between the branches of a
multi-valued function, obtained as an integral of an
algebraic function. If you take the Riemann surface
associated with this algebraic function (that is,
a branched covering of C where it is well-defined),
the period becomes an integral of the holomorphic
differential $fdz$ associated with this function
over a closed loop, that is, an integral of a
holomorphic 1-form over a closed cycle.

The modern definition of "periods" is, more or less,
"the pairing between holomorphic differential forms
and integral homology". However, this notion can
(and often is) extended to Hodge structures, and
this is related to the first notion you mention.

Define the Teichmuller space of a complex manifold
as the space of all complex structures (here the
complex structures are understood as endomorphisms
of $TM$ satisfying $I^2=-Id$ and the integrability
condition) up to isotopies: $Teich= \frac{Comp}{Diff_0}$.
Never mind that this space might be horribly non-Hausdorff;
the period map is naturally defined on $Teich$, and
(if you are lucky) it would help to make sense even of the
non-Hausdorff pathologies.

The period map is the map taking $I\in Teich$
to the Hodge structure on $H^*(M,I)$, which is
understood as a point in the appropriate flag space.
This map is holomorphic, and, if you are lucky,
defines a biholomorphism between $Teich$ and
the space of Hodge structures ("period space").
This holds, unfortunately, only for complex tori,
but weaker versions of this statement are true
for K3, hyperkahler manifolds, complex curves
and in some other cases. These results are
called "global Torelli theorems".

The local Torelli theorems are statements about
the local structure of the period map, saying
(in most cases) that is it locally an immersion;
this is true, for instance, for Calabi-Yau manifolds.

The modern definition of periods is not
entirely equivalent to the traditional, because
the Hodge structure contains more data than
just holomorphic forms; however, if you know
the Hodge structure on cohomology, you know
the pairing between the holomorphic forms
and the integer homology, hence it is an
extension of the XIX century notion.

If you restrict yourself to the first cohomology,
the Hodge structure is a flag $H^{1,0}(M)\subset H^1(M)$;
in this case the XIX century notion of "periods"
coincides with the Hodge-theoretic notion.

Comment: Sorry for a silly question: how to rewrite $\int_0^r\mathrm{d}x/\sqrt{4x^3-ax-b}$ (in the second of the original post) as an integral over a *closed* cycle on a Riemann surface?

Comment: There is a detailed argument in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.04405.pdf The Origins of Complex Geometry in the 19th
Century (Raymond O. Wells, Jr.), Section 6

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should take the Riemann surface of this function in the complex 2-space with coordinates (x, y), and integrate the form dx/y along the path which lifts this interval to one branch until the branching point, then goes around this point and goes back along another lift of this interval, but on a different branch.

Comment: Periods are more general than that (I am not sure whether this kind of "periods" also dates back to the 19th century). [Kontsevich–Zagier](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kontzagi.pdf) gave several examples like $\log(2)$ and $\zeta(3)$ right after the first definition. The MO question that [OP linked](https://mathoverflow.net/q/332387/) also contains an example $\int_{0\le x\le y\le1}(1-x)^{-1}y^{-1}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$, but I don't understand their $H^2(\overline{M_{0,5}}\setminus A,B\setminus(A\cap B))$.

Comment: @Z.M I found most of the details of that relative second cohomology group and the integral (which is $ \zeta(2) $) in the paper of Francis Brown here: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606419